# Redis + Node.js - how do I retrieve the values

Tags: node.js, redis

I am using a Redis database with Node.js.
Using 
`client.hmset("jobs", "jobId_12345", JSON.stringify(jsonJob))`
I store JSON stringified jobs.

Now I want to iterate over all jobs and retrieve both job id and stringified job.

I tried 
`client.hkeys("jobs", function (err, replies) {}`
but that only retrieves the keys.

I tried 
`client.hgetall("jobs", function (err, obj) {}`
but I don't know how to retrieve both key and value from obj.

Any help is greatly appreciated because I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works.
id in the code below is the record id.

```
redisclient.hgetall(key, function (err, dbset) {

  // gather all records
  for (id in dbset) {
       ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Redis HGETALL is the right command (client.hgetall)

As you can also see in redis docs, HGETALL returns all fields and values of the hash stored for the requested key.

I am not 100% sure but `client.hgetall` should return a list with fields and values

```
[field1_name, field1_value, field2_name, field2_value ...]
```