# Express redirect and locals

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using passportjs in order to log user and I try to redirect them after the password verify is complete with angularjs.
But I keep getting  "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" when I try to get user data on another page
Snippet:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, usr, info) {

      res.locals.user = req.usr;
      res.json({msg:true});
      return next();
   })(req, res, next);
});
```

And somewhere else I try to do something like this:

```
user.find({name: req.user.name },function(err,q){
```

Which fire the error "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: Is it supposed to be `req.user` or `req.usr`?

Comment: it is req.usr.I try to name them in case i get errors like this

Comment: So changing `req.user.name` to `req.usr.name` does not work?

Comment: Sadly changing still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide passport with `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` functions in order for passport to store the user in the request object. For more info, check the guide:

http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/

Specifically, look at the bottom section on **Sessions**. Also, consult this similar question:

[Do I implement serialize and deserialize NodesJS + Passport + RedisStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268812/do-i-implement-serialize-and-deserialize-nodesjs-passport-redisstore)

In your case, it looks like you're using `name` instead of `id` to identify users, so wherever you configure passport, you will probably want to do something like:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.name);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(name, done) {
  user.find({name: req.user.name }, function(err, user){
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```