# Retrieving values from keys after hmset command

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a Node.js application with stores posts written by authors in a Redis database. The post is given a unique ID (the variable messageId), and two values are given: the message and the author. The first part of the code looks like so:

```
redisClient.hmset(messageId, "message", req.body.message, "author", req.body.author);
```

So far, so good. What I want to do is be able to retrieve the value of a specific key. I know I can use hgetall() to get all the keys and values for messageId, and I know I can use hkeys to get all the keys for messageId. If I know there will be a key called "message", how can I retrieve the value from message A) from the Redis client, and B) through Node.js?

NOTE: I have seen this: [Redis + Node.js - how do I retrieve the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251493/redis-node-js-how-do-i-retrieve-the-values). It does not tell me what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is `hget` to retrieve a single value, and `hmget` to retrieve multiple values.

See [Redis commands for hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash). The node.js client should support them all.

Something like:

```js
redisClient.hget(messageId, "message");
redisClient.hmget(messageId, ["message", "author"]);
```

Comment: That did just the trick, thank you so much! Now that I am starting to understand the Redis commands and how to use them with Node.JS, I will also take full advantage of the link you provided me.